# Adding 0 for missing data rather than excluding the category in matlab

Tags: matlab, padding, missing-data

I have the two following tables of data, one named data1, the other named data2. The left-hand column is a categorical variable and the right hand column is frequency I would like to rewrite these tables but where there are missing categories in the left-hand column I would like it to put in the correct missing category and then put a '0' in the right-hand frequency column.

```
data1 = [
    
1    170
2    120
3    100
4     40
5     30
6     20
7     10
9     8
10    2
11    1
14    1
];


data2 = [
    
1    240
2    200
3    180
4     60
5     50
6     40
7     30
8     20
9     8
10    2
12    1
19    1
];
```

To be clearer I will explain with an example. In data1, 8 12 and 13 are missing in the left-hand column. I would like matlab to recreate this table but with 0 values for 8, 12 and 13 so it looks as follows. I would also like it to have additional empty categories after '14' because data2 is longer and has more categories. I have also included what data2 should look like with filled in values.

```
data1 = [
    
1    170
2    120
3    100
4     40
5     30
6     20
7     10
8     0
9     8
10    2
11    1
12    0
13    0
14    1
15    0
16    0
17    0
18    0
19    0
];


data2 = [
    
1    240
2    200
3    180
4     60
5     50
6     40
7     30
8     20
9     8
10    2
11    0
12    1
13    0
14    0
15    0
16    0
17    0
18    0
19    1
];
```

I have a handful of datasets which generally all start with 1,2,3,4,5...etc but then they all have slightly different categories on the left-hand column, because where values are missing it just omits the category rather than putting 0. How do i write a code so that it automatically fills in any blanks with a 0. It would be good if the code could identify what the 'highest' number of categories is amongst all the datasets and then fill in blanks based on this.

my aim is to put together a grouped bar chart with data series that are all the same length.

**UPDATED OUTPUT WITH 3 DATASETS**

this is what your AllJoins code outputs in my matlab:

```
     A     table1    table2    table3
     __    ______    ______    ______

     1     170       240       2400 
     2     120       200       2000 
     3     100       180          0 
     4      40        60          0 
     5      30        50          0 
     6      20        40          0 
     7      10        30          0 
     8       0        20          0 
     9       8         8          0 
    10       2         2          0 
    11       1         0          0 
    12       0         1          0 
    14       1         0          0 
    19       0         1          0 
    20       0         0       1800
```

I would like the code to fill in the missing consecutive numbers in column A so that it looks as follows:

```
A     table1    table2    table3
__    ______    ______    ______

 1     170       240       2400 
 2     120       200       2000 
 3     100       180          0 
 4      40        60          0 
 5      30        50          0 
 6      20        40          0 
 7      10        30          0 
 8       0        20          0 
 9       8         8          0 
10       2         2          0 
11       1         0          0 
12       0         1          0 
13       0         0          0
14       1         0          0
15       0         0          0
16       0         0          0 
17       0         0          0
18       0         0          0
19       0         1          0 
20       0         0       1800
```

Comment: I assume you made a type and the last values of the new data 1 should be [19, 1]

Comment: no the last values of the new data 1 in my post should be 19,0 and the last values of the new data 2 is 19,1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the datasets to a table and then use [outerjoin](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.outerjoin.html). Then you can replace the NaNs with whatever you want using [fillmissing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fillmissing.html).

```
table1 = array2table(data1);
table1.Properties.VariableNames = {'A', 'B'};
table2 = array2table(data2);
table2.Properties.VariableNames = {'A', 'B'};

newTable = outerjoin(table1, table2, 'LeftKeys', {'A'}, 'RightKeys', {'A'}, 'MergeKeys', true)
```

which produces:

```
A     B_table1    B_table2
__    ________    ________

 1      170         240   
 2      120         200   
 3      100         180   
 4       40          60   
 5       30          50   
 6       20          40   
 7       10          30   
 8      NaN          20   
 9        8           8   
10        2           2   
11        1         NaN   
12      NaN           1   
14        1         NaN   
19      NaN           1
```

And then get your zeros with `newTable2 = fillmissing(newTable, 'constant', 0)`, which prints:

```
A     B_table1    B_table2
__    ________    ________

 1      170         240   
 2      120         200   
 3      100         180   
 4       40          60   
 5       30          50   
 6       20          40   
 7       10          30   
 8        0          20   
 9        8           8   
10        2           2   
11        1           0   
12        0           1   
14        1           0   
19        0           1
```

**UPDATE**

To combine multiple tables, you can either nest the outerjoin or write a function to loop over it (see [similar Matlab forum question](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/379819-using-the-outerjoin-to-join-more-than-2-tables)). Here's an example.

Given `data1` and `data2` in OP, plus a new `data3`:

```
data3 = [   
1    2400
2    2000
20    1800
];
```

Contents of `myscript.m`:

```
table1 = MakeTable(data1);
table2 = MakeTable(data2);
table3 = MakeTable(data3);

AllJoins = MultiOuterJoin(table1, table2, table3);


% Functions

function Table = MakeTable(Array)
    Table = array2table(Array);
    Table.Properties.VariableNames = {'A', 'B'}; % set your column names, e.g. {'freq', 'count'}
end


function Joined = MultiOuterJoin(varargin)
    Joined = varargin{1};
    Joined.Properties.VariableNames{end} = inputname(1); % set #2 column name to be based on table name
    for k = 2:nargin
      Joined = outerjoin(Joined, varargin{k}, 'LeftKeys', {'A'}, 'RightKeys', {'A'}, 'MergeKeys', true);
      name = inputname(k);
      Joined.Properties.VariableNames{end} = name; % set merged column name to be based on table name
    end
end
```

Which returns `AllJoins`:

```
A     table1    table2    table3
__    ______    ______    ______

 1     170       240       2400 
 2     120       200       2000 
 3     100       180        NaN 
 4      40        60        NaN 
 5      30        50        NaN 
 6      20        40        NaN 
 7      10        30        NaN 
 8       0        20        NaN 
 9       8         8        NaN 
10       2         2        NaN 
11       1         0        NaN 
12       0         1        NaN 
13       0         0        NaN 
14       1         0        NaN 
15       0         0        NaN 
16       0         0        NaN 
17       0         0        NaN 
18       0         0        NaN 
19       0         1        NaN 
20     NaN       NaN       1800
```

Comment: how could i alter this so that it does the same thing but with 3 datasets?

Comment: that's fantastic thank you so much. I have just copy and pasted your code into my matlab and 'AllJoins' does not reproduce the same output that you have put in the post i think you have used data1 and data2 from the incorrect part of my post. I have added an update on to my post to show what your code outputs on my matlab

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to change the maximum length of the array, this is a generic answer. The maximum length is `max(data1(:,1))`, but you can compute this in any way, e.g. the maximum value of multiple arrays.

```
% make new data
new_data1=zeros(max(data1(:,1),2));
new_data(:,1)=1:max(data1(:,1));    

% Fill data. You can do this in a loop if its easier for you to understand.
% in essence, it says: in all the data1(:,1) indices of new_data's second column, put data1(:,2)
new_data(data1(:,1),2)=data1(:,2);
```

Comment: doesn't this only uses the maximum length of data1, which would be 14? I want the maximum length to be the larger of the two datasets, which is 19 but i want it to automatically detect this. Further, can max be used with categorical variables?

Comment: @Boo I am certain you can figure out that you can use `max(some_value_for_example_leght_data1, some_other_value_for_example_length_data2)`. or any other way to obtain your desired length. Your code does not show any categorical variable, just two matrices.

Comment: the data is being imported from an excel document and the left hand column is a categorical variable. i had to write the data set out to simplify posting it on here. I was hoping the code would incorporate detecting the largest dataset